# Some of the Restkit Methods are Not Available

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm following this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL10r9h9qRA) to learn using restkit, but some of the RK methods used in ProjectListViewController.m doesn't seem to exists. The methods used in the viewDidLoad aren't working. It is like this:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [manager.mappingProvider objectMappingForClass [Project class]];
```

the method mappingProvider doesn't seem to exist.

```
[manager loadObjectAtResourcePath:@"/projects" objectMapping: mapping delegate: self];
```

the above method also doesn't show in the code completion.

I'm using Xcode 5 and restkit version 0.20.0

pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of RestKit you're using is (relatively) new (but you should start using the latest version. The video references the old version of RestKit. Use the current RestKit [documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) and the test code that is part of the repository to get a handle on how to use it.

If you really want to follow the video, checkout the old version of RestKit (but best not to learn RestKit that way).